Persisting files in a nextjs application
I have a nextjs app with many forms on multiple pages. These forms include completing text and adding files( .txt, .docx, .pdf, .pptx, .jpeg, .png etc.). How do you handle persisting these files between page refreshes?
Localstorage doesn't seem to be a good option because 5mb is too small for my use case.
